# Android use third party softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have installed new `Softkeyboard` in my device and i want that keyboard to use in my application .

what will i have to do for using this new keyboard by my application.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Its a user setting which keyboard they use. It would be terribly frustrating if every app could force their own keyboard on the users.

You can start an intent to open the keyboard settings, to give people the option to use your keyboard.

Comment: means when ever application will launch it will ask for keyboards..there is not programming way to open particular keyboard for particular app.